# Downloading images with node.js

Tags: node.js, image, download

I'm trying to write a script to download images using node.js. This is what I have so far:

```
var maxLength = 10 // 10mb
var download = function(uri, callback) {
  http.request(uri)
    .on('response', function(res) {
      if (res.headers['content-length'] > maxLength*1024*1024) {
        callback(new Error('Image too large.'))
      } else if (!~[200, 304].indexOf(res.statusCode)) {
        callback(new Error('Received an invalid status code.'))
      } else if (!res.headers['content-type'].match(/image/)) {
        callback(new Error('Not an image.'))
      } else {
        var body = ''
        res.setEncoding('binary')
        res
          .on('error', function(err) {
            callback(err)
          })
          .on('data', function(chunk) {
            body += chunk
          })
          .on('end', function() {
            // What about Windows?!
            var path = '/tmp/' + Math.random().toString().split('.').pop()
            fs.writeFile(path, body, 'binary', function(err) {
              callback(err, path)
            })
          })
      }
    })
    .on('error', function(err) {
      callback(err)
    })
    .end();
}
```

I, however, want to make this more robust:

1. Are there libraries that do this and do this better?
2. Is there a chance that response headers lie (about length, about content type)?
3. Are there any other status codes I should care about? Should I bother with redirects?
4. I think I read somewhere that `binary` encoding is going to be deprecated. What do I do then?
5. How can I get this to work on windows?
6. Any other ways you can make this script better?

Why: for a feature similar to imgur where users can give me a URL, I download that image, and rehost the image in multiple sizes.

Answer (score 474, accepted):

I'd suggest using the [request module](https://github.com/mikeal/request). Downloading a file is as simple as the following code:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    request = require('request');

var download = function(uri, filename, callback){
  request.head(uri, function(err, res, body){
    console.log('content-type:', res.headers['content-type']);
    console.log('content-length:', res.headers['content-length']);

    request(uri).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename)).on('close', callback);
  });
};

download('https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png', 'google.png', function(){
  console.log('done');
});
```

Comment: Cool! Is there a way to check size and content type before actually downloading it?

Comment: Sure is, `request.head`. I edited my example to show the content-type and content-length before downloading the file.

Comment: Where does it download the images to?

Comment: Awesome to build automatic http://shields.io/ badges!

Comment: @CezaryWojtkowski, I'm getting error message "socket hang up", do you have any good idea how to solve this?
Thanks Or.

Comment: Not working for me( Image corrupted

Comment: @Gofilord its download the image to your root directory.

Comment: Can you change the location of where they are saved? If you wanted them in a specific folder?

Comment: If you want to do this with promises/fancy async-await syntax use the `request-promise` module. E.g. `let fileContents = await request(myUrl)`

Comment: Thanks, works in Chrome for downloading images from the web!

Comment: Can you download a image to a html <img> element?

Comment: `request` is deprecated.

Comment: To choose specific folder you need to change `'google.png'` for `'path/to/google.png'`. The system understand google.png as ./google.png

Comment: How I can make this asynchronous?

Answer (score 62):

You can use **[Axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)** (a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)-based HTTP client for Node.js) to download images in the order of your choosing in an [asynchronous environment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function):

```
npm i axios
```

Then, you can use the following basic example to begin downloading images:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const axios = require('axios');

/* ============================================================
  Function: Download Image
============================================================ */

const download_image = (url, image_path) =>
  axios({
    url,
    responseType: 'stream',
  }).then(
    response =>
      new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        response.data
          .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(image_path))
          .on('finish', () => resolve())
          .on('error', e => reject(e));
      }),
  );

/* ============================================================
  Download Images in Order
============================================================ */

(async () => {
  let example_image_1 = await download_image('https://example.com/test-1.png', 'example-1.png');

  console.log(example_image_1.status); // true
  console.log(example_image_1.error); // ''

  let example_image_2 = await download_image('https://example.com/does-not-exist.png', 'example-2.png');

  console.log(example_image_2.status); // false
  console.log(example_image_2.error); // 'Error: Request failed with status code 404'

  let example_image_3 = await download_image('https://example.com/test-3.png', 'example-3.png');

  console.log(example_image_3.status); // true
  console.log(example_image_3.error); // ''
})();
```

Comment: Great example ! But barely readable code, try the [standard](https://standardjs.com/) style :D

Comment: @camwhite I prefer [semicolons](https://standardjs.com/rules.html#semicolons). ;)

Comment: You really should attach 'finish' and 'error' events to the write stream, wrap them in a Promise and return the promise. Otherwise you may try to access an image that hasn't been completely downloaded yet.

Comment: Wouldn't the await would make sure the image downloads completely before trying to access?  @jwerre

Comment: @jwerre @FabricioG I've updated the function `download_image` to capture the 'finish' and 'error' event for the returned promise

Comment: Don't think this is working, copied the example but nope...

Comment: example_image_1 is always undefined and no error or info to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 55):

I ran into this problem some days ago, for a pure NodeJS answer I would suggest using Stream to merge the chunks together.

```
var http = require('http'),                                                
    Stream = require('stream').Transform,                                  
    fs = require('fs');                                                    

var url = 'http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png';                    

http.request(url, function(response) {                                        
  var data = new Stream();                                                    

  response.on('data', function(chunk) {                                       
    data.push(chunk);                                                         
  });                                                                         

  response.on('end', function() {                                             
    fs.writeFileSync('image.png', data.read());                               
  });                                                                         
}).end();
```

The newest Node versions won't work well with binary strings, so merging chunks with strings is not a good idea when working with binary data.

*Just be careful when using 'data.read()', it will empty the stream for the next 'read()' operation. If you want to use it more than once, store it somewhere.

Comment: Why not stream the download directly to disk?

Comment: had a lot of problems with chunking strings together as it created a corrupt file, but this did it

Comment: Alternatively you can use an array for `data`, and replace `data.read()` with `Buffer.concat(data)`. This way we don't need to import the stream module

Comment: For `https://...` urls, use the `https` module, as seen in [@chandan-chhajer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49687365/2441655).

Comment: How do you check for errors using this? I'm downloading a file which ends up being corrupted somehow... trying to debug this. Is setting the encoding a possible solution?

Comment: Thanks everyone.
Used Nihey's answer as main code.
Used ternary operator plus some simple regex to determine whether to use http or https like Venryx mentioned.
Used Ching Chang's answer to avoid importing Stream, and it worked perfectly. :)

Comment: Property 'push' does not exist on type 'Stream'.

Answer (score 13):

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const http = require('http');
const https = require('https');

const downloadImageToUrl = (url, filename) => {

   let client = http;
   if (url.toString().indexOf("https") === 0) {
      client = https;
   }
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      client.get(url, (res) => {
          res.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename))
          .on('error', reject)
          .once('close', () => resolve(filename))
      })
  })
};

await downloadImageToUrl('https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png', 'public/uploads/users/abc.jpg');
```

Comment: your function doesn't trigger the callback

Answer (score 10):

if you want progress download try this:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var progress = require('request-progress');

module.exports = function (uri, path, onProgress, onResponse, onError, onEnd) {
    progress(request(uri))
    .on('progress', onProgress)
    .on('response', onResponse)
    .on('error', onError)
    .on('end', onEnd)
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(path))
};
```

how to use:

```
  var download = require('../lib/download');
  download("https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png", "~/download/logo.png", function (state) {
            console.log("progress", state);
        }, function (response) {
            console.log("status code", response.statusCode);
        }, function (error) {
            console.log("error", error);
        }, function () {
            console.log("done");
        });
```

note: you should install both request & request-progress modules using:

```
npm install request request-progress --save
```

Comment: This worked great, but wanted to suggest adding a `statusCode` check. A 500 statusCode for example, will not hit the `'on("error", e)`. By adding a `on('response', (response) => console.error(response.statusCode))` it greatly facilitates debugging,

Comment: You can edit my answer :)

Answer (score 8):

This is an extension to Cezary's answer. If you want to download it to a specific directory, use this. Also, use const instead of var. Its safe this way.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const request = require('request');
var download = function(uri, filename, callback){
  request.head(uri, function(err, res, body){    
    request(uri).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename)).on('close', callback);
  });
};

download('https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png', './images/google.png', function(){
  console.log('done');
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Building on the above, if anyone needs to handle errors in the write/read streams, I used this version. Note the `stream.read()` in case of a write error, it's required so we can finish reading and trigger `close` on the read stream.

```
var download = function(uri, filename, callback){
  request.head(uri, function(err, res, body){
    if (err) callback(err, filename);
    else {
        var stream = request(uri);
        stream.pipe(
            fs.createWriteStream(filename)
                .on('error', function(err){
                    callback(error, filename);
                    stream.read();
                })
            )
        .on('close', function() {
            callback(null, filename);
        });
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: `stream.read()` appears to be outdated, throws an error `not a function`