# How can I get a JavaScript triggered download using Nightmare js?

Tags: javascript, nightmare

The file download is triggered by clicking on a button. The button has an `onclick` attribute which initiates the file download.

Since I don't have the file url direclty. I cant use the [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) module to request the file as described in [Download a file using Nightmare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27109563/download-a-file-using-nightmare)

Comment: Can you please provide url/code with which you are trying?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `nightmare-download-manager`and do something like this:

```
nightmare.on('download', function(state, downloadItem) {
    if(state == 'started') {
        nightmare.emit('download', 'yourfilename.txt', downloadItem);
    } else if(state == 'completed') {
        console.log('Donwload completed');
    } else if(state == 'interrupted') {
        endNightmare();
    } else if(state == 'cancelled') {
        endNightmare();
    }
});

nightmare
.downloadManager()
.goto(url)
.click('#javascriptDownloadBtn')
.waitDownloadsComplete()
.then(function() {
    return nightmare.end();
})
```

Comment: how do you do this for images? like replicate right click save image.