# Nightmare JS: How to Download file - clicking the download button opens a new window that automatically closes afterwards

Tags: javascript, node.js, nightmare

I tried and did not download the file:

1) using nightmare-download-manager & nightmare-inline-download plugin 
2) execute nightmare without the graphic active {show:false}

1) & 2) Result: 
After clicking download - a new electron window opens and just hangs there...

3) overwriting the window target='_self'

`.evaluate(() => {
      window.open(jQuery('#download')[0].click, '_self'); 
   }`

Electron opens 2 new windows( _self window and normal window) and both just hangs there....

Please help :(

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You shouldn't need [0] on an ID selector because only 1 element should exist

Comment: Thanks! That was not the problem though

Comment: @Zel please tell us what the problem was. It helps fellow users, like me, who need an answer to your question. And if you answer your own question you also get reputation :)

Comment: Think I am having a problem similar to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27109563/download-a-file-using-nightmare). The proposed solution there doesn't fix the problem for me though