# Downloading file to AWS s3 using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to use [npm file download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12740659/downloading-images-with-node-js) to download an image I scraped off a site to my aws s3 server. I keep getting the following:

> if (!self.body) throw new Error('params.Body is required');
>                             ^
>   Error: params.Body is required

I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction of fixing my code. Below is the code in entirety:

```js
//required node modules
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var fs      = require('fs');
var s3      = require('s3');
var AWS     = require('aws-sdk');

var url = 'https://medium.com/@benjaminhardy/8-things-every-person-should-do-before-8-a-m-cc0233e15c8d'; //url of site

AWS.config.loadFromPath('./config.json');
var s3bucket = new AWS.S3({params: {Bucket: 'crawlerdemo'}});

request(url, function(err, resp, body){
  $ = cheerio.load(body);
  links = $('img'); //get the image tags
  $(links).each(function(i, link){ //go through every link on page
    image_path = $(link).attr('src');
    var tmp = image_path.lastIndexOf('/');
    var filename = image_path.substring(tmp+1, image_path.length); //set file name
    var download_tmp = download(url, filename, function(){});
    var params = {Key: filename,Body: download_tmp};
    s3bucket.upload(params, function(err, data){
      if(err){
        console.log("Error: ",err);
      }
    });
  });
});

//download method
var download = function(uri, filename, callback){
  request.head(uri, function(err, res, body){
    request(uri).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename)).on('close', callback);
  });
};
```

Comment: Your `var params = {Key: filename,Body: download_tmp};` is incorrect. The Body has to be string or buffer but download_tmp in your code is always going to be `undefined`.

Comment: Something like this: https://gist.github.com/techgaun/cf37344a758f377a313f might work