# Angularjs saving files on server from URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I am working on an Angular app where I receive an array of image URLs that are hosted on another server. The CORS has been enabled so that is not an issue. I want a way to save those URLs as images in a directory on my server and have pointers to those images in the DB. Currently I just save those image URLs as an array in the DB. I wanted to know if there are some useful libraries out there on node.js (which I use for server stuff) that can help me simplify this.

Comment: you want everyday users to upload images to your server?

Comment: I think this answer would help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12740659/downloading-images-with-node-js?answertab=active#tab-top