# Access to content on sony camcorder

Tags: camera, sony

I'm playing with the API on a camcorder Sony CX-625. I can start/stop a record, change zoom over a Wifi connection.
This is nice, but ...
Now, I need to download the content store on the SD card over Wifi with the API. I have make a lot of research, but it seem the function is not available.

Maybe another model of Sony Handycam can give this functionnality. Anybody can help me in this research ?

My goal is to have a camcorder (or an IP Camera with quality of a camcorder), remotely administrable by an API (start/stop record, manage zoom, get/delete the content)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to download the image using HTTP get. For instance if you run the "actTakePicture" command you will be returned the url for the image. Having this url will allow you to download the image. How you download the image depends on what language you are using. For instance here is an example of how to download an image over HTTP get using nodejs:

[Downloading images with node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12740659/downloading-images-with-node-js)

To find out how to download the image using your particular language try a google search on "download an image using http get {language of choice}"