# node get request response incomplete

Tags: node.js, ssl, httprequest

When I request images using node request library of the given url, the images loaded are not complete. After storing the loaded image it looks like https://ibb.co/i5xVAR

However the request finishes without an error and has status code 200. For me it seems that the ssl connection gets closed. Other tools like browser or curl transfer the image complete.

```
const request = require('request');
    const r1 = request({
        url: 'https://open.hpi.de/files/f1d16619-9813-4d59-96b3-d84908929b23',
        encoding: 'binary'
      }, (err, response, body) => {
        if (err) {
         console.log(err);
         return;
        }
        // complete file should be loaded
        // content and body length should match
        // read ECONNRESET should not be thrown
        console.log('body length', body.length);
        console.log('response content length', response.headers['content-length']);
      });
```

Comment: you can try this : ```request(url).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename)).on('close', callback);```

Comment: Because not all data is returned at once: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12751657/5115872

Comment: piping to filesystem is fine, but i need the response as buffer finally not a stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The open.hpi.de host is closing the connection prematurely. You can add a `Connection: keep-alive` header to the request and the connection will remain open until the transfer is actually complete:

```
const request = require('request');
const r1 = request({
  url: 'https://open.hpi.de/files/f1d16619-9813-4d59-96b3-d84908929b23',
  encoding: 'binary',
  headers: {
    "Connection": "keep-alive"
  }
}, (err, response, body) => {
  // do the things
});
```

Comment: thanks, that solves it really simple without further code changes.