# Load external file with node.js and use with jwt.sign

Tags: node.js, jwt, node-modules

I am trying to load an external .pem file to sign with JWT in node.js, but jwt.sign does not return anything.
It seams that the .pem file is not loading correct.

Hoping that someone can help.

Here is the code:

```
function(properties, context) {

    const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
    const https = require('https');


        https.get(properties.privateKeyName, res => {
            // Initialise an array
            const bufs = [];

            // Add the data to the buffer collection
            res.on('data', function (chunk) {
                bufs.push(chunk)
            });

            // This signifies the end of a request
            res.on('end', function () {
                // We can join all of the 'chunks' of the file together
                const privateKey = Buffer.concat(bufs);

                const issuer = properties.issuer;
                const client_id = properties.client_id;
                const aud = 'https://revolut.com'; // Constant
                const payload = {
                  "iss": issuer,
                  "sub": client_id,
                  "aud": aud
                };

                const token = jwt.sign(payload, privateKey, { algorithm: 'RS256', expiresIn: 60 * 60});

                return {
                    'jwt_token': token,
                    'jwt_test': 'test',
                }


            });
        })

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe for private key algorithm is not RS256. Its RSA or ECDSA.

Comment: This is the docs, that I am following from Revolut:
https://revolutdev.github.io/business-api/#setting-up-access-to-your-own-account

It seams that algorithm must be RS256.

Comment: @ReneMeldgaard You are right. My bad. BTW, is your pem file hosted in another server?

Comment: Yes it is. And that seams to be the issue. I can't store it local.

Comment: I would suggest you to write the Buffer in a file and verify the file.

Comment: Ok, can I get you to share an example? :)

Comment: @ReneMeldgaard Do you mean you wanna share an example with me?

Comment: No, I am hoping that you can share how to use Buffer with my code :)

Comment: What I would do is, `fs.writeFile('key.pem', privateKey)` to write the buffer in a file named key.pem and then check the file manually if the file is okay or not. This is not a solution, just to verify if the buffer is okay.

Comment: I have a theory here. The `res` variable doesn't contain only privatekey dada but it also contains all the relevant http headers (ex: content-type) etc. So, your `privateKey` variable contains not only the private key but also all the http headers etc. That is way it mismatches.

Comment: I could not get it to work, with an external file. My solution ended up being to use the content of the pem file direct.
But thanks for your time :)

Comment: That might be a solution, let me try to find a way to extract the content of only the file.

Comment: You might try this way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30939791/3858638

Comment: Still the same, it's still like the external file does not get read properly.
I will just use the content of the file and not try to load it :)