# How to save image with plain nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to save an image (link obtained) with just plain nodejs (no additional 'require' beside those natively packaged with node).  Let say I have image with link:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JkxM.jpg

needing this image to be save into folder ./picsFolder

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Why dont you read existing libraries? But basically its get the stream and write it.

Comment: Use `http.request()` - https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback

Comment: You can also check out this thread. There are answers that use vanilla node: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12740659/downloading-images-with-node-js

Comment: @Estradiaz
Is there a more approachable way to understand nodejs docs for beginner, like an example?

Answer (score 1):

You can tweak this snippet.

An HTTP request is an (input) stream of data that you can direct to another (output) stream.

To go deeper with [streams read here](https://github.com/maxogden/mississippi#mississippi)

```
const https = require('https')
const fs = require('fs')
const options = {
  hostname: 'i.imgur.com',
  port: 443,
  path: '/UiiCTfN.jpg',
  method: 'GET'
}

const req = https.request(options, res => {
  console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`)

  const imgStream = fs.createWriteStream('./myimg.jpg')

  res.pipe(imgStream)
})

req.on('error', error => {
  console.error(error)
})

req.end()
```

Comment: Thanks Manuel Spigolon, this work too.  Is the port value arbitrary?

Comment: No, it should be 443 for https and 80 for HTTP, it depends on the protocol and by the endpoint, you are calling. if it is a custom API it could be 3000 as well

Answer (score 0):

ref thread:
[Downloading images with node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12740659/downloading-images-with-node-js)
by Nihey Takizawa

```js
var http = require('https'),                                                
    Stream = require('stream').Transform,                                  
    fs = require('fs');                                                    

var url = 'https://i.imgur.com/UiiCTfN.jpg';                    

http.request(url, function(response) {                                        
  var data = new Stream();                                                    

  response.on('data', function(chunk) {                                       
    data.push(chunk);                                                         
  });                                                                         

  response.on('end', function() {                                             
    fs.writeFileSync('./picsFolder/yourImgName.png', data.read());                               
  });                                                                         
}).end();
```