# How can I download images to client in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to download an image to the client in my little node app.  Here is my code:

```
app.post("/image-download", (req, res, next) => {
  const image = path.join(__dirname, "/images", `/${req.body.imageName}`);
  res.setHeader("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");
  res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment");
  res.send(image);
});
```

Where this image is stored in the path that I am constructing.  I using fetch API on the front end and am able to receive the image and log it to the console, but how can I download it?  Is this something that needs to be done on the front end?  Thanks for the help!!

Edit: Just to clarify, what I want to mimic is the unsplash.com functionality.  I want users to be able to download the images and this is my download route for their selected image.

Comment: Do you want to download it with the console or a download button in the frontend?

Comment: Maybe you can try this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12740659/downloading-images-with-node-js

Comment: I want to download it so the client can save the file to their local drive

Comment: @ARVOCI that example downloads the image to the local machine (I believe), I want to send the image to the client so they can download it locally (similar to unsplash.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `res.download`: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.download

```js
app.post("/image-download", (req, res, next) => {
  const image = path.join(__dirname, "/images", `/${req.body.imageName}`);
  res.download(image);
});
```

By the way, it's cleaner to use the `GET` method, because you don't create an entity but return one.

Comment: Hi Naor thanks for the reply!  I tried this as well and it doesnt work, at lease out of the box.  Is there something special I should do on the front end?  I am using the fetch API, would I need to start the download from the client side?  Also thanks for the note on GET, maybe its better to put the image name as a query param instead of in the body.

Comment: Do you get an error or something?
And, yes, it is better to pass it as param. (https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.params)

Comment: no errors but I don't get the download.  check unsplash.com how you can download an image to your local desktop on their images, I am trying to do exactly this.  Wondering what I need to do with the file on the front end?  I receive the file but how do I then download it?

Comment: Hi Naor thanks for your help but I just solved it using anchor tags on the front end instead of making the fetch request.  Still wondering if there is a way to use fetch to get to this result?