# How to save images from a link into a folder using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Im devleoping a discord bot ( discord.js) so, I want to create a command which is like -

`+mask Name_Surname(Image URL)` and when a user uses that cmd, the bot saves the image from the image url provided into a folder with the name provided by the user. (This is like for a signature bot)

An illustrative example for the above is provided -

`The users uses a cmd .upload Name (URL) and the bot saves the image ( in .png format) to a folder which already exists with the "Name" provided by the user.`

[Click Here to View the example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F43Gm.png)

Im pretty new to this, so what I would like is an example code for the above ^^ so that I can work it out myself. I hope someone can help me! Thanks

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service. Make an attempt at coding this yourself and then come here when you encounter issues.

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: This one could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12740659/downloading-images-with-node-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if you are using Node.js you can use `request` npm library.

```js
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content.startsWith('+mask')) {
    const args = message.content.split(' ');
    const imageURL = args[1];
    var imageName = ""; //Image name

    request(imageURL).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(imageName));
    const attachment = new MessageAttachment(imageURL);
    message.channel.send(attachment);
  }
});
```

Request library docs - https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#streaming

Comment: Thank you boss! Helped a lot <3